# Do I get anything for letting people play on my seesaw?

Tags: happy-street

Various villagers and visitors play on my seesaw. It doesn't look like I get money for this like I do when they visit my shops - is there any benefit to people using the seesaw? I know I get a bonus to nearby shops for placing it, but is there any benefit for people using it?